# I ran the following commands by mistake in my Ubuntu 21.04 machine and then everything became broken

Tags: permissions, sudo, system, 21.04, chown

Good evening, please I ran the following commands by mistake in my Ubuntu 21.04 machine and then everything became broken...

```
sudo chown john: /*
sudo chown john: /**
sudo chown john: /**/**
```

and sudo is no longer working

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

EDIT:
after referring to [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set) and [Sudo doesn't work: "/etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513523/sudo-doesnt-work-etc-sudoers-is-owned-by-uid-1000-should-be-0) I ran the following commands in Live USB it worked again...

```
sudo chown root:root /* -R
sudo chown root:root /** -R
sudo chown root:root /**/** -R
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/** -R
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/**/** -R
sudo chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d /etc/sudo.conf -R
sudo chmod 4755 /etc/sudoers
sudo chmod 4755 /etc/sudo.conf
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

EDIT 2:
and the following commands too...

```
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/libexec/**
sudo chown root:root /usr/libexec/**
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/libexec/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

Comment: How do you run three commands by mistake against all directories? You may after al ot of work and many days or weeks get this working again. But I would recommend a re install from scratch.

Comment: the path wasn't meant to be root... i meant /downloads

Comment: a useful hint for the future: before performing this type of operation perhaps **first** use `ls` in order to see what will be impacted by your command *before* committing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. That is... bad. You should reinstall Ubuntu. Copy all the files you care about somewhere safe. Copying them to two safe places is better, if you can. If the `cp` (or, depending on your "safe place", `mount` as well) command doesn't work to copy these files, you can do this from a Live CD. Personally, I'd just use a LiveCD to be safe, but if the `cp` command works, that is probably fine too. **Double-check that they are in a safe location.**

You need to reinstall, similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/43621/1438484). Sadly, the `**` glob from your command means it ran it recursively. Technically, it may be possible to manually fix it, but it would be very time-consuming.

This last part isn't helpful now, but... **take regular backups of your system in case of something going wrong**. Also, *RAID is not a backup*.

Comment: When you try to `mv` several files to a directory by `mv files* mistyped_directory`, only the last moved file survives, the others get overwritten. `mv files* mistyped_directory/` throws an error and your files stay intact.

So, there are cases where you want to type the `/` out. Learned by painful experience...

Comment: I edited it. I wasn’t aware of that, but thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You're welcome. Better to learn it here than by trying to move 100+ files like I did.